# Hive - No enum constant org.apache.parquet.schema.OriginalType.s (state=,code=0)

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table in hive. Which while creating I used the following partitions, format etc.

```
PARTITIONED BY (
`abc_dt` string,
`xyz_last` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
'hdfs://cluster/tmp/oip/logprint_poc_new'
 TBLPROPERTIES (
'bucketing_version'='2',
'discover.partitions'='true',
'transient_lastDdlTime'='1609830728')
```

When I am running the query: `select * from oip_poc` I am getting the following exception at the end. Although the query is returning the schema of the table correctly in the beginning of the result. But at the end of the result I see the following exception.

```
INFO  : Completed compiling command(queryId=hive_20210122112612_d5edb9e8-d954-41e9-ae1e- c1deca9e8e47); Time taken: 4.192 seconds
INFO  : Executing command(queryId=hive_20210122112612_d5edb9e8-d954-41e9-ae1e-c1deca9e8e47): select * from oip_poc
INFO  : Completed executing command(queryId=hive_20210122112612_d5edb9e8-d954-41e9-ae1e-c1deca9e8e47); Time taken: 0.041 seconds
INFO  : OK
Error: java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.parquet.schema.OriginalType.s (state=,code=0)
```

I am not able to understand why I am getting this. Is this because while creating the table I made a mistake or something else. I am new to hive. Any help is appreciated.

Following is the screenshot of the exception:

[image]

Comment: Full exception message probably will help to understand what is the issue.

Comment: @leftjoin Actually apart from this there is just schema related information and there are 3500 columns so its huge. That's why I am not pasting the complete log. Exception is just one line and that's there. Anyways I have added ascreenshot also